# Information needed about a closed question

Tags: discussion

So I asked [This Question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11118/how-can-i-calculate-the-evaporation-rate-for-a-hazmat-spill) earlier and am still having hard time understanding how I am supposed to ask this in a more intuitive way, so the boards will accept my question in general.

I have went back through a few things and added more identifiers for the variables being used.

Essentially, it is two questions wrapped up into one post. If I need to break them up into two, that isn't a hard task to do, just want to make sure it is accepted by the community.

Answer (score 2):

I will remove the majority of your question. This is what is left:

> I was given formulas for General Evaporation for a spill calculator I am building.
>
> What I would like:
> Verification that these formulas will work for an approximation of Evaporation of a Substance.
> If not, what formulas would be more appropriate?

You seem to be wanting to know what formulae are appropriate, but you don't say why you don't trust the ones that were given to you or what other research you have done. The actual formulae are almost a distraction.

In other words, "What are you asking?"

Comment: I don't trust the formulas given, because they were given by another student, assigned to this task. These formulas are not found in any workbook, website, ect. I am always skeptical about using other peoples work without documentation making sure they have proof to backup their claims that this stuff will work. I am asking precisely this: Are these formulas suitable to use as an Approximation for Evaporation? If Not, what would be a better formula?

I am not an engineer, I am a computer science/mathematics major. This project has nothing to do with school though. it is a work project.

Comment: The closest thing I can find to an equation I can use is from this: [Here](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/evaporation-water-surface-d_690.html) but I am unable to decipher the characteristics it is asking since it is extremely technical in that field. I'm willing to do some research but I still have yet to find an acceptable formula/equation I can implement in this program. Another example is [HERE](http://www.mmshah.org/publications/ASHRAE%202014%20Evaporation%20paper.pdf) which equation #7 is the formula it says to use for spills but I have no idea how it works.

Comment: @Duck All of that sounds like very useful information that would've been good in your question. You explain why you might not trust the given equations and also state the research that you have done on your own. Those are both items that help clarify what your question is.